# Tensorflow inference very slow on first time run in docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I built a docker image for a server that does inference with tensorflow. I installed tensorflow-gpu with pip in the docker image. It works fine for my machine with titan x gpus. But when I ran the docker container on another machine with 1080 ti gpus. The first run becomes incredibly slow, takes about 90 seconds, usually it takes 7 seconds on the first run and 1 second in the following runs. I tried to set tf_cudnn_use_autotune to 0, and also mount a folder to save the cuda cache. But it doesn't really solve the problem. Any one has any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/performance/overview).
I find this.

> *After running TensorFlow once, the compiled kernels are cached by CUDA. If using a docker container, the data is not cached and the penalty is paid each time TensorFlow starts*.

Comment: Any idea, where these cached kernels can be located?